# Better midi playback on mac

Tags: lilypond, midi

I am trying to write scores for some popular bollywood songs using lilypond. I am checking the correctness of score by playing back the midi file. I am observing that the playback quality by different midi players are vastly different. Specifically timidity on Mac produces a very "jerky" (for want of a better word) output. If I upload the same midi file to some online apps like bandlab the output is much more "smooth". I am unable to attach audio files to this question but if you visit https://test.meedee.in you can listen to the audio and observe the difference. I also observed that if I transpose the song up by an octave even the output from timidity sounds smooth.

Questions:

I use a mac and timidity fits very well into my workflow but unfortunately does not produce kind of audio that I am looking for. Importing into bandlab every time is going to be painful. What other options do I have? I also tried timidity on linux and mediaplayer on windows. Both of them are atrocious.

Can I improve the audio on mac itself by using articulation? I tried including "articulate.ly" and using slurs. It made absolutely no difference to the midi output.

Comment: In the examples you attach, the rhythm is quite complex. There are overlapping pauses in the first and second measure, the third measure doesn't seem to add up to 4/4... moreover, the note grouping doesn't follow typical conventions. Is that all intended? Could it be it contributes to issues with playback?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use MuseScore? It has excellent playback for a free program and definitely is easier to use than lilypond. Of course if you want to make publishable scores than lilypond is better, but I think it would be faster to do 95% in Musescore and then finalise in Lilypond

Comment: @Creynders I did try MuseScore. I found it excruciatingly painful to enter notes via GUI. I prefer text input.

Comment: @user1079505 I generally use autonotesplitting feature of lilypond. Sometimes it does produce weird looking PDFs. But it may not contribute to playback issues, because the same file plays fine with other player.

Comment: "I found it excruciatingly painful to enter notes via GUI." It may be, but it is best UI out there, much better than Sibelius. Use 3.6.2 version, not 4.

Comment: You can use LilyPond to generate the midi file, and then import it into MuseScore for playback.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace lilypond does not support musicxml. Only way to import would be through midi or PDF. Both are very error prone. Can I use musecore from command line to just play the midi file ? That might solve my problem.

Comment: tbh, no matter what you use for playback, trying to make a score sound like a real orchestra is a lost cause. There is just too much missing from the performance. You aren't going to be able to use it for anything more than checking all the notes are right.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't really expect to. An "acceptable" ( by my own standards) level of performance will be alright. Right now I find the intrumental parts are quite acceptable but the vocal parts suck. That is what I am trying to improve.

Comment: So the analogy is: MIDI is like sheet music. It's digital and there's extra information, but it's still a set of instructions. The same instructions can be rendered by the cheesy stuff that would play on Geocities websites in 1999, or by expensive suites that emulate full symphony orchestras. (Also, note, the human voice has always been a synthesis challenge...)

Comment: Even on instrumental parts you need to anticipate ot the strings etc. Vocals are always tough, even in choosing what instrument to use. My project mix engineer once threatened our programmers, "If I hear one more dodgy alto sax or pan floot from anyone this week, I'll eat them alive."

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree. But even if I get a sort of decent output, I feel good about it. Its a personal project after all. Which soundfont/instrument combination do you use for vocals?

Comment: I don't. I use vocals for vocals. I stopped making midi files for a living 20 years ago, after having done it for a decade. ;) Even back then, soundfonts weren't really up to the task. They're too simplistic really. We worked for specific hardware units & we had a lot more programming flexibility than with a simple soundfont. [tbh, even back then I farmed out the stuff with vocal lines to other people - I used to do instrumentals, usually as product demos.]

Comment: I know my aims were probably a lot different to what you're trying to achieve, but good midi programming is **hard**. We went through something like 300 applicants & online 'finds', each going through two week's rigorous training, to hone it down to the 10 best, plus 15 others we could give the more run of the mill jobs to. The average skill level was bad to atrocious, even after training. Some of the guys were fabulous transcribers, so they would be assigned an assistant [or me] to get their work down in a manageable manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Midi is **not** some kind of audio format, midi is a protocol that tells a synthesizer or sampler what notes to play. So it is quite expected that different synthesizers will produce different sounding results.

TiMidity is a sampler that uses Ultrasound patches or .sfx or .sf2 soundfonts. This is what provides TiMidity with the samples it uses. The soundfont that your Mac installation comes with probably has very small amounts of samples per instrument, meaning that e.g. on a violin vibrato will become slower the lower your notes are. This leads to what you consider "jerky" sound.

So the solution would be to find yourself a soundfont that sounds adequate to you. There are a number of popular free soundfonts out there.

Comment: "So the solution would be to find yourself a soundfont" The solution is to use a normal physically based renderer that does not have anything pregenerated... Pianoteq...

Comment: @Lazy Can you provide more info on where to find soundfonts and how to install ?

Comment: @kargirwar Checkout the Arch doc for this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Timidity++ You will need to locate the config file on your system (I do not use Mac OS, so I cannot tell). Soundfonts simply need to be downloaded, and you need to specify the path to the soundfont in the config file. For soundfonts you might e.g. try https://schristiancollins.com/generaluser.php or simply google "general midi soundfont".

Comment: @Lazy I tried a differnt soundfont and there was immediate improvement in the playback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles on this: I dumped timidity and started using fluidsynth. Getting much better playback. I am using FluidR3_GM.sf2 soundfont.